# Add Like button with Django + Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

Hi I create my first project like stackoverflow(question-answer). I used this guid from Tango with Django http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book17/chapters/ajax.html to add like button with ajax. And nothing hapened. Don't see any request in console. I'm noob in Django, and it's my first encounter with jquery.

```
apps/questions/models:

class Answer(models.Model):

    text = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    resolve = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    author = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)

apps/questions/views:

@login_required
def add_like(request):

    ans_id = None
    if request.method == 'GET':
        ans_id = request.GET['answer_pk']

    likes = 0
    if ans_id:
        ans = Answer.objects.get(id=(int(ans_id)))
        if ans:
            likes = ans.likes + 1
            ans.likes = likes
            ans.save()

    return HttpResponse(likes)

apps/questions/ulrs: 
url:
   url(r'add_like/$', views.add_like, name='add_like'),

 question.html:
    {% for answer in answers %}
    <div class="container-fluid no-padding">
        {{ answer.text }}   
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid  author-question">
    <p>posted: {{ answer.date.day|stringformat:"02d" }}.{{ answer.date.month|stringformat:"02d"}}.{{ answer.date.year}}</p>
    <p>by: {{ answer.author.username }}</p>
    </div>
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="likes" data-ansid="{{ answer.id }}">
        like | <strong id="like_count">{{ answer.likes }}</strong>
    </button>
    {% endif %}

js/ajax.js:

    $('#likes').click(function(){
    var ansid;
    ansid = $(this).attr("data-ansid");
            $.get('/questions/add_like/', {answer_id: ansid}, function(data){
        $('#like_count').html(data);
    $('#likes').hide();
});
});
```

Comment: Is the `js/ajax.js` properly loaded in your page?

Comment: yes, in my "head.html" that include "base.html"                                                `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
     <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
          <script src="{% static 'js/ajax.js' %}"></script>`

Comment: No, I'm asking if it got properly loaded on your page? Check the source of the loaded page. If it is, check the browser console to see what's happening. Whether the request is being made or not.

Comment: yes, it's loaded    `<script src="/static/js/ajax.js"></script>` i check in browser, and nothing hapened in neetwork page, when i clicked button

Comment: Hm, try copy pasting the code into the console and click the button then. Does anything happen?

Comment: sorry, i don't understand, code from my view to server console and then click button?

Comment: Paste the code in `/js/ajax.js` to the browser console and then click the button and see what happens.

Comment: console display this    `<button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="likes" data-ansid="1">
   like | <strong id="like_count">0</strong>
  </button>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are creating buttons in a for loop, and naming them the same way, you have multiple elements on the page with the same id. Because of this you get unpredictable results. You should either give each button its own id, or change the jQuery selector to select the buttons based on the appropriate class.

For example, you could have:

```
{% for answer in answers %}
    <div class="container-fluid no-padding">
        {{ answer.text }}   
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid  author-question">
    <p>posted: {{ answer.date.day|stringformat:"02d" }}.{{ answer.date.month|stringformat:"02d"}}.{{ answer.date.year}}</p>
    <p>by: {{ answer.author.username }}</p>
    </div>
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <button class="btn btn-default likes-button" type="button" data-ansid="{{ answer.id }}">
        like | <strong id="like_count">{{ answer.likes }}</strong>
    </button>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

And then for the javascript

```
$('.likes-button').click(function(){
    var ansid;
    ansid = $(this).attr("data-ansid");
            $.get('/questions/add_like/', {answer_id: ansid}, function(data){
        $('#like_count').html(data);
    $('#likes').hide();
});
});
```

Comment: Have you tried without the trailing slash in `urls.py`? You are also going to have to correct the GET parameter - in `ajax.js` you are passing `answer_id` and in `add_like` view you are expecting `answer_pk`

Comment: i change code, like you say. it customise like-button, now when i paste js code in console, I see 404: GET 127.0.0.1:8000/apps/questions/add_like/?answer_id=12 404 (NOT FOUND)   Maybe I have problem with view? request.GET don't recieve "answer_id"

Comment: Also, it is possible you included your `questions/urls.py` at a different url. Can you update your question with the main `urls.py`?

Comment: i change in view to "answer_id", try without slash in urls, still doesn't work. In console "answer_id" display correct

Comment: u right, problem probably with urls. I update questions with main    `urls.py`. Still  doesn't work. Console recieve   127.0.0.1:8000/apps/questions/add_like/?answer_id=9 . but I'm on the page http://127.0.0.1:8000/questions/get/15/

Comment: You haven't updated your question with main `urls.py`. We need to see how you include your `questions.urls.py`... Also, have you removed the trailing slash from both urls as well as javascript, when testing?

Comment: my main    `urls.py`:      `urlpatterns = [  url(r'^questions/', include('apps.questions.urls')), ]`       my     apps.questions.urls:      `url(r'all/$', views.all_questions, name='all_questions'),   
 url(r'get/(?P<question_pk>[0-9]+)/$',views.get_question,name='get_question'),    
    url(r'add_like/$', views.add_like, name='add_like'),`    sorry for the bad design my comment

Comment: i remove slash like this:  `url(r'add_like$', views.add_like, name='add_like')`,      `url(r'add_answer/(?P<question_pk>[0-9]+)$', views.add_answer, name='add_answer')`,

Comment: You shouldn't put your code in comments. I said edit the question... It's unreadable if you put it in the comment. And to answer your question, I think if you just remove the trailing slash in your javascript, it should work.

Comment: i change ajax.js    `$.get('/questions/add_like'`   delete   `/apps/` . Now its worked, but only if i put code in console

Comment: I would guess that it means your ajax.js does not load properly then. Check the file in browser's development tools to see the content of `ajax.js`. Also, I did not even know you had `/apps/` in the url. You should really make a bigger effort to put relevant information in your question.

Comment: i see it in sources, code is correct. Thank a lot for help. You spent a lot of time on me,  next tim i will put more detailes on my question.

Comment: i put script  donw body, and it's worked.  but incorrectly, the counter is updated on the same button once, on the next, after reload page, and my answer change places after reload :) . Thank you again, sorry for my programing and english skills

Comment: Well, but that is a different problem :). You could also wrap your code in `$(document).ready()` which would make it work even if it was at the top of html. But putting it on the bottom is better anyway. Glad you solved it :)